# popToViewController Executing First

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, parse-platform

When the post button is pressed, the function below executes. In the function, all the objects that are retrieved using the Parse backend are appended to the `groupConversation` array, which is a global array. However, when I reference the array in the `UITableViewController` that is popped to towards the end of the function and use `println()` to print the content of the array, the array is empty. However, when I use `println()` in the `UIViewController` that contains this function the array is shown to contain one object. In the console, the `println()` of the `UITableViewController` that is popped to once the button is pressed, is executed before the `println()` of the `UIViewController` that contains the function below. How can I make the functon below execute completely before popping to the `UITableViewController`.

```
@IBAction func postButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    //Adds Object To Key
    var name=PFObject(className:currentScreen)
    name["userPost"] = textView.text
    name.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (success: Bool!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

        if success == true {

            self.textView.text=""


        } else {

            println("TypeMessageViewController Error")

        }


    }
    //Gets all objects of the key
    var messageDisplay = PFQuery(className:currentScreen)
    messageDisplay.selectKeys(["userPost"])
    messageDisplay.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil{
            for object in objects {
                var textObject = object["userPost"] as String
                groupConversation.append(textObject)

                }
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure

        }
        println("Type message \(groupConversation)")
    }
    navigationController!.popToViewController(navigationController!.viewControllers[1] as UIViewController, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here `messageDisplay.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock`. As you are doing this in background thread, it will be separated from main thread. And your main thread will execute as it should be.

So it before finishing the task you main thread popping the view.

```
messageDisplay.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
    if error == nil{
        for object in objects {
            var textObject = object["userPost"] as String
            groupConversation.append(textObject)

            }
    } else {
        // Log details of the failure

    }
    println("Type message \(groupConversation)")
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.navigationController!.popToViewController(navigationController!.viewControllers[1] as UIViewController, animated: true)
        return
    }
}
```

Pushing and popping in background thread may cause problem. So get the main thread after executing the task in background and then pop in main thread.

In swift single statement closures automatically return the statement return value. In your specific case, it's attempting to return an instance of [AnyObject]?, which is the return value of popToViewControllerAnimated. The closure expected by dispatch_afteris Void -> Void instead. Since the closure return type doesn't match, the compiler complains about that.

Hope this helps.. ;)

Comment: How can I make it so that the `popToViewController()` method executes after the `messageDisplay.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock`

Comment: I get two errors when I use your edit `'[AnyObject]?' is not a subtype of 'Void'` on the line `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())` and  `Implicit use of 'self' in closure; use 'self.' to make capture semantics explicit` on the same line.

Comment: @StevenR > use self.navigationcontroller

Comment: I just tried the new code you updated, but unfortunately the same errors are there.

Comment: I just put a `self` before `navigationController!.viewControllers[1]` and now I only get `'[AnyObject]?' is not a subtype of 'Void'` as a error.

Comment: @StevenR> add return after popping

Comment: What do you mean to add `return` after popping. I don't see `popping in my code`. Thanks again, I'm new to ios development.

Comment: @StevenR > Read the last paragraph of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are running into a very common issue with asynchronous code. Both your `...InBackgroundWithBlock {}` methods run something in the background (async).

The best example I have found to explain it is this:

When you start an async code block, it is like putting eggs on to boil. You also get to include something that should be done when they finish boiling (the block). This might be something like remove the shell and slice the eggs.

If your next bit of code is "butter bread, put eggs on bread" you might get unexpected results. You don't know if the eggs have finished boiling yet, or if the extra tasks (removing shell, slicing) has finished yet.

You have to think in an async way: do this, then when it is finished do this, etc.

In terms of your code, the call to `popToViewController()` should probably go inside the async block.

Comment: Where would you recommend to put the popToViewController() method in regards to the async block.

Comment: At the end of the sync block, after you've processed any records. The other answer has given a great example of pushing it back to the main (UI) thread.